# Android MapView: animateTo doesnt work while map is panning

Tags: android

The code below does the following:
When checking the "focus" checkbox, the map animates to the single overlay item in the map.
There is one problem:
When i drag the map so that the map is still moving when I check the checkbox, the checking has no visual effect.
Any ideas?

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
AssetMarkersOverlay itemizedOverlay;
private CheckBox autofocusCheckBox;
MapView mapView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(4);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble_blue);
    itemizedOverlay = new AssetMarkersOverlay(drawable);

    String assetName = "TEST";
    int lat = 3;
    int lon = 3;

    ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPointList = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);

    autofocusCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.showInMap);
    autofocusCheckBox.setTag(point);
    autofocusCheckBox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked && buttonView.getTag() != null) {
                        focusAsset((GeoPoint) buttonView.getTag());
                    }
                }
            });

    geoPointList.add(point);
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(lat, lon, assetName, assetName);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    mapOverlays.clear();
    mapView.postInvalidate();
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    fitPoints(geoPointList, mapView);
    mapView.postInvalidate();

}

private void focusAsset(GeoPoint point) {
    mapView.requestFocus();
    mapView.clearAnimation();
    mapView.getController().stopAnimation(true);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(14);
    mapView.getController().animateTo(point);
    mapView.postInvalidate();
}
```

Comment: any luck in finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I used an AsyncTask to fix a similar issue. It works sometimes but not all the time. Basically I just call animateTo a few times with some delays. Worth noting it appears getMapCenter returns the location it is animating to rather than the current true center as I tried using this to detect if it got to the new location yet or not and it doesn't work a lot of the time. Also it appears no animation will last longer than 1000 milliseconds at least on ICS so potentially waiting that long before making a call could fix your issue.