# MapView - Stop the scroll when the locate button is clicked

Tags: android, android-mapview

In the image below (from [Polaris](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=824)), you can see a "locate" `ImageButton` at the top-right of the `MapView`.

I got a custom one (an `ImageView`) and handles myself its clicks.

Right now, when a user drags the map and then (during the drag) click on the locate button, it does nothing until the map stopped moving.

**What I would like to accomplish is to stop the map from scrolling.**

Here is what I tried (thx to *blazzerbg*): `mMap.getController().stopAnimation(false);`
But no go.

I know I have those functions, maybe they interfeer?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    // Disables multi-touch (zoom in/out)
    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        return true;
    }

    // Get the map if a drag is done
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // ...
    }

    // Disables double-tap
    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Seems I'm not the only one...

- [Android MapView MapController stopAnimation not stopping animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622340/android-mapview-mapcontroller-stopanimation-not-stopping-animation)
- [Action after mapview (swipe) animation stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194643/action-after-mapview-swipe-animation-stops)
- [Android MapView: animateTo doesnt work while map is panning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383131/android-mapview-animateto-doesnt-work-while-map-is-panning)

Answer (score 0):

There is method in MapController

```
public void stopAnimation(boolean jumpToFinish)
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController#stopAnimation%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable user tracking button in any case you want:
There is such method:

```
 /**
     * Enable/disable user tracking on this {@link PolarisMapView}.
     * 
     * @param enabled True if user tracking is enabled, false otherwise.
     */
    public void setUserTrackingButtonEnabled(boolean enabled) {
```

this method attaches a listener for centering the view based on user location :

```
private final OnClickListener mOnUserTrackingButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MapViewUtils.smoothCenterOnUserLocation(PolarisMapView.this, mMyLocationOverlay, R.string.polaris__unable_to_locate_you);
        }
    };
```

Comment: That is not what I want. I have my own method, and it works great. I have a button, and it works great. What I want is the `stopAnimation()` method to work.